# Call to DB to check if a value exists

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to run a query to check if what is entered into a textfield matches that of what is stored in a database.

The current code:

```
</form>
<br />
<h2>Discount Code</h2>
<br />
<form method="POST" action=''>
        <input type="text" name="discount" />
        <input type="submit" name="discountSubmit" value="Apply" />

    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['discountSubmit'])){

    $discountCode = $_POST['discount'];

    $codeCheck = mysqli_query("SELECT code FROM discount WHERE code = $discountCode");

    var_dump($codeCheck);
    }

    ?>
    </form>
```

However, upon clicking discountSubmit the var_dump returns NULL so it would lead me to assume $codeCheck is wrong, however it looks right to me.

I connect through the database through another page so the issue doesnt lie there

Database Structure:

```
id        code       discount      expire
```

---

```
1         WEB10       10.00      2013-06-01
```

Expire isn't relevant just at the moment.

Comment: When `$codeCheck` is `false` you need to do `echo mysqli_error($conn)` to see the error message.

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) hole. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: @MarcB: nice! +1. Going to have to bookmark this for future answers :)

Comment: @MattMeadows I think you got mysqli_query procedural style and oo style mixed up, reread [the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, code is not an integer value. Hence, enclose it by single quotes. You should also include the `$conn` (connection variable) while using `mysqli_query()` statement - [mysqli_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

```
$codeCheck = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT code FROM discount WHERE code = '$discountCode'");
```

[EDIT]
If you are including the connection page inside this page, try doing these:

**connect.php**

```
function connect(){
   $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $un, $pw, $db);
   return $conn;
}
```

Now, call this function from the current page and get the connection variable:

```
$conn = connect();
```

Now, use `$conn` for the `mysqli_query()` function.

---

Change the if condition as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['discount']))
```

Comment: Although you mention OP's probably most important problem - the lack of a $conn first param - you don't elaborate on that in your post...

Comment: Have added the single quotes around the variable, however it still dumps NULL

Comment: @MattMeadows you should use the connection reference of the current mysql connection in `mysqli_query()`

Comment: @kevin okay - maybe also add that $codecheck will be a mysqli_result type object, not the field value, a fetch type call will still be required

Comment: Within my index.php i have require_once("connect.php");
This links to a php file with the database connect, so it should still be connected otherwise the products wouldn't be appearing

Comment: @kevin Thankyou for spending the time to help me. 
I have now changed my code to what you have suggested and it var_dumps bool(false)

Comment: @MattMeadows try making the change mentioned above.

Comment: With the if statement kept the same, have just ran an if statement on mysqli_num_rows($codeCheck)>0 and it finds the correct code and displays the right messages!

Comment: @MattMeadows can u post the code of both the pages? that could help.

Comment: All is working well.
When I type in the correct discount code, that I know is in the db, it echos accepts and when not, it echos denied. 
I can now work on the calculations for the code acceptance.
Thankyou again!

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't mix SQL with HTML
2. You shouldn't use a function without reading its **manual page** first
3. You shouldn't use bare API with mysqli, but some abstraction library instead.

A better version for your code, courtesy of [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql#safemysql) which works the natural way you expect from mysqli_query but don't get it.

```
<?php 
$check = NULL;
if(isset($_POST['discountSubmit']))
{
    $sql   = "SELECT code FROM discount WHERE code = ?i";
    $check = $db->getOne($sql, $_POST['discount']);
}
?>
<h2>Discount Code</h2>
<br />
<form method="POST" action=''>
        <input type="text" name="discount" />
        <input type="submit" name="discountSubmit" value="Apply" />
</form>
<?php var_dump($check); ?>
```